# First time file not uploading in blueimp Jquery File Upload

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using Blueimp JqueryFileUpload, when i tried to upload my very first file its not uploading. But After i tried the same file  or any file its working.

I can't figure out whats goes wrong for the very first upload.

While debugging i can found that the fileupload method not triggered for the first upload but followed consecutive uploads say second,third,..  its triggering

```
           $('#fileUpload').fileupload({
                url: 'home/upload',
                dataType: 'json',
                done: function (e, data) {
                   //do something
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you generating the input file field after the page loads? I had the same issue because I forgot to initialize `.fileupload()` after the input field was appended.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `.fileupload()` method after form or form field is generated. 
like

```
$('#fileupload'+rowNum).fileupload();
```

here `$('#fileupload'+rowNum)` is a dynamic form id.